# MVC Razor page not displaying values from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, model-view-controller

I have an mvc and I need to display the values from the model, in the view, once the user has filled in some form parameters. When I put a breakpoint in the code, the model contains the correct values from the form, however when I try to display it, it doesn't work.
Here is my form & at the top, I have a test title where I am trying to display one of the values I need to be displayed in the view.

```
@using SharedComponents
@model FIAECBC
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CBC";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Styles.Render("~/Content/FormStyle.css")

<main id="main" style="background-color:deeppink; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
    <!-- ======= Describe Section ======= -->
    <section class="section section-describe">

        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 150px;">
            <div class="row">
                <h3></h3>
                <h1 style="color:black">composite val: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Neutrophils)</h1>
                <div class="col-md-4" data-aos="fade-up">
                    <h2>Engine Test</h2>



                    @using (Html.BeginForm("CBC", "FIAE", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                    {

                        <div class="field" tabindex="1">
                            <label for="name" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>Your Username
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" style="color: darkgray" name="username" placeholder="e.g. Adam Smith" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="field" tabindex="2">
                            <label for="email" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                                Email:
                            </label>
                            <input type="email" style="color:darkgray" name="email" placeholder="email@domain.com" required />
                        </div>
                        <label>
                            Select Biological Gender: <br />
                        </label>


                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserGender, FIAECBC.GetSelectItems(), new { @class = "dropitdown" })



                        <br />
                        <div class="field" tabindex="3">
                            <label for="platelets" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>Platelets
                            </label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" style="color: darkgray" name="Platelets" placeholder="160" required /> x10^3/mm^3
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="field" tabindex="4">
                            <label for="MCH" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>MCH
                            </label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" style="color: darkgray" name="MCH" placeholder="30" required /> pg
                        </div>
                        <div class="field" tabindex="4">
                            <label for="MCV" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>MCV
                            </label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" style="color: darkgray" name="MCV" placeholder="85" required /> u^3
                        </div>
                        <div class="field" tabindex="4">
                            <label for="Neutrolphils" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>Neutrolphils
                            </label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" style="color: darkgray" name="Neutrophils" placeholder="85" required />%
                        </div>
                        <div class="field" tabindex="4">
                            <label for="MCHC" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>MCHC
                            </label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" style="color: darkgray" name="MCHC" placeholder="85" required /> g/dl
                        </div>
                        <div class="field" tabindex="4">
                            <label for="MCHC" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>Lympthocytes
                            </label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" style="color: darkgray" name="Lympthocytes" placeholder="85" required />%
                        </div>
                        <div class="field" tabindex="4">
                            <label for="MCHC" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>Monocytes
                            </label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" style="color: darkgray" name="Monocytes" placeholder="85" required />%
                        </div>
                        <div class="field" tabindex="4">
                            <label for="MCHC" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>Eosinophils
                            </label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" style="color: darkgray" name="Eosinophils" placeholder="85" required />%
                        </div>
                        <div class="field" tabindex="4">
                            <label for="MCHC" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>Haemoglobin
                            </label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" style="color: darkgray" name="Haemoglobin" placeholder="85" required /> g/dl
                        </div>
                        <div class="field" tabindex="4">
                            <label for="MCHC" style="color:white">
                                <i class="far fa-user"></i>Haematocrit
                            </label>
                            <br />
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" style="color: darkgray" name="Haematocrit" placeholder="85" required /> %
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" id="submit" style="background-color:black" onchange="">Submit</button>
                        <br />




                    }

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">






                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

        </section>



    </main><!-- End #main -->
```

This is the external class where I perform some logic and manipulation to the data before I send it to the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SharedComponents;
using static SharedComponents.FIAECBC;

namespace FIAE
{

    public class FIAEngine
    {
        decimal d_Neutrophils;
        decimal d_Lymphocytes;
        decimal d_Monocytes;
        decimal d_Eosinophils;
        decimal d_Platelets;
        decimal d_Haematocrit;
        decimal d_Haemoglobin;
        decimal d_MCV;
        decimal d_MCH;
        decimal d_MCHC;
        string UserID;
        string Gender;

        string Neutrophils;
        string Lymphocytes;
        string Monocytes;
        string Eosinophils;
        string Platelets;
        string Haematocrit;
        string Haemoglobin;
        string MCV;
        string MCH;
        string MCHC;

        string NeutrophilRAG;
        string LymphocytesRAG;
        string MonocytesRAG;
        string EosinophilsRAG;
        string PlateletsRAG;
        string HaematocritRAG;
        string HaemoglobinRAG;
        string MCVRAG;
        string MCHRAG;
        string MCHCRAG;

        public void setcbcvals(decimal[] inputs, string _UserID, string _Gender)
        {

            
            d_Neutrophils = inputs[0];
            d_Lymphocytes = inputs[1];
            d_Monocytes = inputs[2];
            d_Eosinophils = inputs[3];
            d_Platelets = inputs[4];
            d_Haematocrit = inputs[5];
            d_Haemoglobin = inputs[6];
            d_MCV = inputs[7];
            d_MCH = inputs[8];
            d_MCHC = inputs[9];
            UserID = _UserID;
            Gender = _Gender;

            Neutrophils = "Neutrophils";
                Lymphocytes = "Lymphocytes";
                Monocytes = "Monocytes";
                Eosinophils = "Eosinophils";
                Platelets = "Platelets";
                Haematocrit = "Haematocrit";
                Haemoglobin = "Haemoglobin";
                MCV = "MCV";
                MCH = "MCH";
                MCHC = "MCHC";

            NeutrophilRAG = "i";
            LymphocytesRAG = "i";
            MonocytesRAG = "i";
            EosinophilsRAG = "i";
            PlateletsRAG = "i";
            HaematocritRAG = "i";
            HaemoglobinRAG = "i";
            MCVRAG = "i";
            MCHRAG = "i";
            MCHCRAG = "i";

            try
            {

                //male calculations
                if (Gender == "Male")
                {
                     NeutrophilRAG = FindMaleRAG(d_Neutrophils, 1);
                     LymphocytesRAG = FindMaleRAG(d_Lymphocytes, 2);
                     MonocytesRAG = FindMaleRAG(d_Monocytes, 3);
                     EosinophilsRAG = FindMaleRAG(d_Eosinophils, 4);
                     PlateletsRAG = FindMaleRAG(d_Platelets, 5);
                     HaematocritRAG = FindMaleRAG(d_Haematocrit, 6);
                     HaemoglobinRAG = FindMaleRAG(d_Haemoglobin, 7);
                     MCVRAG = FindMaleRAG(d_MCV, 8);
                     MCHRAG = FindMaleRAG(d_MCH, 9);
                     MCHCRAG = FindMaleRAG(d_MCHC, 10);

                    //set view model values to the form values
                    var cbcmodel = new FIAECBC
                    {
                        d_Neutrophils = d_Neutrophils,
                        d_Lymphocytes = d_Lymphocytes,
                        d_Monocytes = d_Monocytes,
                        d_Eosinophils = d_Eosinophils,
                        d_Platelets = d_Platelets,
                        d_Haematocrit = d_Haematocrit,
                        d_Haemoglobin = d_Haemoglobin,
                        d_MCV = d_MCV,
                        d_MCH = d_MCH,
                        d_MCHC = d_MCHC,

                        Neutrophils = Neutrophils,
                        Lymphocytes = Lymphocytes,
                        Monocytes = Monocytes,
                        Eosinophils = Eosinophils,
                        Platelets = Platelets,
                        Haematocrit = Haematocrit,
                        Haemoglobin = Haemoglobin,
                        MCV = MCV,
                        MCH = MCH,
                        MCHC = MCHC,

                        rag_Neutrophils = NeutrophilRAG,
                        rag_Lymphocytes = LymphocytesRAG,
                        rag_Monocytes = MonocytesRAG,
                        rag_Eosinophils = EosinophilsRAG,
                        rag_Platelets = PlateletsRAG,
                        rag_Haematocrit = HaematocritRAG,
                        rag_Haemoglobin = HaemoglobinRAG,
                        rag_MCV = MCVRAG,
                        rag_MCH = MCHRAG,
                        rag_MCHC = MCHCRAG,

                        };

                    string me = "9";
                   
                }
                else if (Gender == "Female")
                {
                     NeutrophilRAG = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Neutrophils, 1);
                     LymphocytesRAG = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Lymphocytes, 2);
                     MonocytesRAG = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Monocytes, 3);
                     EosinophilsRAG = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Eosinophils, 4);
                     PlateletsRAG = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Platelets, 5);
                     HaematocritRAG = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Haematocrit, 6);
                     HaemoglobinRAG = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Haemoglobin, 7);
                     MCVRAG = FindfeMaleRAG(d_MCV, 8);
                     MCHRAG = FindfeMaleRAG(d_MCH, 9);
                     MCHCRAG = FindfeMaleRAG(d_MCHC, 10);

                    //set view model values to the form values
                    var cbcmodel = new FIAECBC
                    {
                        d_Neutrophils = d_Neutrophils,
                        d_Lymphocytes = d_Lymphocytes,
                        d_Monocytes = d_Monocytes,
                        d_Eosinophils = d_Eosinophils,
                        d_Platelets = d_Platelets,
                        d_Haematocrit = d_Haematocrit,
                        d_Haemoglobin = d_Haemoglobin,
                        d_MCV = d_MCV,
                        d_MCH = d_MCH,
                        d_MCHC = d_MCHC,

                        Neutrophils = Neutrophils,
                        Lymphocytes = Lymphocytes,
                        Monocytes = Monocytes,
                        Eosinophils = Eosinophils,
                        Platelets = Platelets,
                        Haematocrit = Haematocrit,
                        Haemoglobin = Haemoglobin,
                        MCV = MCV,
                        MCH = MCH,
                        MCHC = MCHC,

                        rag_Neutrophils = NeutrophilRAG,
                        rag_Lymphocytes = LymphocytesRAG,
                        rag_Monocytes = MonocytesRAG,
                        rag_Eosinophils = EosinophilsRAG,
                        rag_Platelets = PlateletsRAG,
                        rag_Haematocrit = HaematocritRAG,
                        rag_Haemoglobin = HaemoglobinRAG,
                        rag_MCV = MCVRAG,
                        rag_MCH = MCHRAG,
                        rag_MCHC = MCHCRAG,
                    };


                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            string po = "op9";

            //return inputs;
        }

        public string FindMaleRAG(decimal i, int x)
        {
            String connString = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServerCon"]);

            //for each row, do this
          
                //find the threshld values
                String thresholdquery = @"select * from dbo.malethreshold where ID = " + x;
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(thresholdquery, conn))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                //compare threshold values t posted values from form
                                string composite = Convert.ToString(reader[1]);
                                decimal redlow = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[2]);
                                decimal greenlow = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[3]);
                                decimal greenhigh = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[4]);
                                decimal redhigh = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[5]);

                                if (i < redlow)
                                {
                                    // Red low
                                    return ("Red Low");
                                }
                                else if (i > redlow && i < greenlow)
                                {
                                    // Amber Low
                                    return ("Amber Low");
                                }
                                else if (i >= greenlow && i <= greenhigh)
                                {
                                    //green
                                    return ("Green");
                                }
                                else if (i > greenhigh && i < redhigh)
                                {
                                    //amber high
                                    return ("Amber High");
                                }
                                else if (i > redhigh)
                                {
                                    // Redhigh
                                    return ("Red High");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //sorting error
                                    return ("error in sorting");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            
            return ("sorting error");
        }

        public string FindfeMaleRAG(decimal i, int x)
        {
            String connString = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServerCon"]);

            //for each row, do this

            //find the threshld values
            String thresholdquery = @"select * from dbo.malethreshold where ID = " + x;
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(thresholdquery, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            //compare threshold values t posted values from form
                            string composite = Convert.ToString(reader[1]);
                            decimal redlow = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[2]);
                            decimal greenlow = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[3]);
                            decimal greenhigh = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[4]);
                            decimal redhigh = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[5]);

                            if (i < redlow)
                            {
                                // Red low
                                return ("Red Low");
                            }
                            else if (i > redlow && i < greenlow)
                            {
                                // Amber Low
                                return ("Amber Low");
                            }
                            else if (i >= greenlow && i <= greenhigh)
                            {
                                //green
                                return ("Green");
                            }
                            else if (i > greenhigh && i < redhigh)
                            {
                                //amber high
                                return ("Amber High");
                            }
                            else if (i > redhigh)
                            {
                                // Redhigh
                                return ("Red High");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //sorting error
                                return ("error in sorting");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return ("sorting error");
        }

    }

   


}
```

Then Finally here is my model which contains all the values I need to display as well as a dropdown list for the view

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SharedComponents
{
    public class FIAECBC
    {
        public string Neutrophils { get; set; }
        public string Lymphocytes { get; set; }
        public string Monocytes { get; set; }
        public string Eosinophils { get; set; }
        public string Platelets { get; set; }
        public string Haematocrit { get; set; }
        public string Haemoglobin { get; set; }
        public string MCV { get; set; }
        public string MCH { get; set; }
        public string MCHC { get; set; }

        

        public decimal d_Neutrophils { get; set; }
        public decimal d_Lymphocytes { get; set; }
        public decimal d_Monocytes { get; set; }
        public decimal d_Eosinophils { get; set; }
        public decimal d_Platelets { get; set; }
        public decimal d_Haematocrit { get; set; }
        public decimal d_Haemoglobin { get; set; }
        public decimal d_MCV { get; set; }
        public decimal d_MCH { get; set; }
        public decimal d_MCHC { get; set; }

        public string rag_Neutrophils { get; set; }
        public string rag_Lymphocytes { get; set; }
        public string rag_Monocytes { get; set; }
        public string rag_Eosinophils { get; set; }
        public string rag_Platelets { get; set; }
        public string rag_Haematocrit { get; set; }
        public string rag_Haemoglobin { get; set; }
        public string rag_MCV { get; set; }
        public string rag_MCH { get; set; }
        public string rag_MCHC { get; set; }



        public Gender UserGender { get; set; }

        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectItems()
        {
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "Male" };
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value = "Female" };
        }

        public bool Bookkeeping { get; set; }

    }
 

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }

}
```

Comment: where are you returning a view? I don't see you passing the model back in... (could be I'm missing it)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to pass the model back into the view